# How to make Tensorflow Lite even faster on ARM devices (running quantized tflite mobilenet v1 model)

Tags: tensorflow, arm, tensorflow-lite

I have tested the tflite object detection example on Pixel 2. It is amazing that the inference time is as low as ~50ms. The question is: can we do it even faster on ARM devices?

The two major operations in mobilenet v1 are `CONV_2D` and `DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D`. For `CONV_2D` we have the support of `gemmlowp` library which use both inline NEON assembly and multithreading. However, for `DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D` it only uses NEON intrinsics. Will tensorflow team implement it with NEON assembly in the future?

Is there any other way that I can reduce the inference time? Any thoughts are highly appreciated!